# Get Child object with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to get child object ID from my postgres db through a query. Basically, my app is doing the following:

User asks a question.
2 answers are provided and sent to DB.

Now, I'd like to get the ID of last question from DB.

My models.py

PARENT:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
__tablename__ = 'User'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
username = Column(String, unique=True)
email = Column(String, unique=True)
password = Column(Binary)
registration_date = Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
lastquestion = Column(String, unique=True)
questions = db.relationship('Question', backref='submitter')
```

CHILD:

```
class Question(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'Question'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
submitterid = Column(Integer, db.ForeignKey('User.id'))
userquestion = Column(String)
response1 = Column(db.String, default='dummy')
response2 = Column(db.String, default='dummy1')
timeofquestion = Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='questions')
```

CHILD OF CHILD

```
class Answer(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'Answer'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
questionid = Column(Integer, db.ForeignKey('Question.id'))
answer = Column(db.String, default="default answer")
is_liked = Column(Integer, default='0')
is_disliked = Column(Integer, default="0")
```

I am trying to get the last question's ID through the following query:

```
    questionid = db.session.query(Question).order_by(Question.id.desc()).first()
```

The response I'm getting is:

```
 <Question 545>
```

Probably a rookie question, but I'd like to get 545 only, as that is the ID of my last question from DB, and then the following would work:

```
new_db_entry = Response(questionid=questionid, response=response, is_liked="0", is_disliked=0)
    db.session.add(new_db_entry)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: `db.session.query(Question).order_by(Question.id.desc()).first().question_id` I guess ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley - not quite, but you helped me figure it out, thanks. It's:
`db.session.query(Question).order_by(Question.id.desc()).first().id`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me, for anyone else struggling with same:

```
db.session.query(Question).order_by(Question.id.desc()).first().id
```